# Weights of graph as length of line in matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure, weighted-graph

I'm trying to construct a kind of graph in matlab:
For each vertex I know its neighbours (thus, I have the edge list), and the distance between vertex-neighbour. This distance is saved as weight of the edge.
So, the weights are actually the physical distances between the nodes.

For now I could only associate a wider line to bigger weights but is not enough.

I actually would like having longer lines associated to a bigger weights, so that I could visually construct a suitable geometry from my data.

Any tips?

EDIT: The distances are such that the drawing is possibile.

[image]

Comment: Your edge should be represented with straight lines ?

Comment: yes, that would be better. Intuitively, if each distance (weight) is equal to the same value W, then the graph would be a regular mesh, like a simple grid. Otherwise, I would like this difference in weights to be shown with longer/shorter lines

Comment: If we have 3 vertex A,B and C and the weight A-B = 1, B-C = 1 and C-A = 3 then there is no possible representation with straight lines (at least in an euclidian space). How such a case should be treated ?

Comment: I did add a picture to make you see an example of these drawing

Comment: If you're using MATLAB's [`graph`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.html) class, `plot` will do it for you, given the [right parameters](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.graphplot.layout.html#mw_3b90f3f2-7b4f-4263-bbb3-1e4a496b9181).

Comment: @beaker Well, no. as you can see from the picture at your link, the edge labels are the weight values: the length of the edges are entirley uncorrelated with the weights

Comment: Yeah, the edge length *proportional* to the weight rather than exact.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/examples/matlab/win64/GraphLayoutBasedOnEdgeWeightsExample_01.png Take the edges with 2 and 17 as labels. the have the same lenght. the edge with weight 6 is smaller than the one with edge 2

Comment: That's the example of the default behavior of `plot` with a force layout. If you scroll down to the next bit of code where they modify it with `layout(p,'force','WeightEffect','direct')`, you'll see [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/examples/matlab/win64/GraphLayoutBasedOnEdgeWeightsExample_02.png).

Comment: Ok, I feel super stupid now! thank a lot

Comment: No worries, I probably should have been more explicit about which code I was referring to.